# What is System.Numerics.Vector.ConditionalSelect used for?

Tags: c#, .net, simd, system.numerics

Can anyone explain preferably with an example what/when/how `System.Numerics.Vector.ConditionalSelect` can be used?

I cannot understand much from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn889226(v=vs.111).aspx).

Comment: it is the same as double c = cond ? a : b;  but for multiple values at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `condition` parameter is actually `Vector<int>` when using 4 byte overloads of the `ConditionalSelect` such as the ones with `Vector<int>` or `Vector<float>` arguments. `condition` is `Vector<long>` when using 8 byte versions, etc.

To expand on @Hans' comment in your question, `condition` means something like: `double c = cond == -1 ? a : b;`. That is, when `cond == -1`, it selects the left values. When `cond == 0`, it selects the right values.

When `cond` is something else, I saw some results I don't particularly understand yet and didn't actually research.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Length depends on your Vector<int>.Count. In my computer it is 4
        Vector<int> vector1 = new Vector<int>(4); //vector1 == {<4, 4, 4, 4>}
        Vector<int> vector2 = new Vector<int>(5); //vector2 == {<5, 5, 5, 5>}
        Vector<int> mask = Vector.GreaterThan(vector1, vector2); //mask == {<0, 0, 0, 0>}
        Vector<int> selected = Vector.ConditionalSelect(mask, vector1, vector2); //selected == {<5, 5, 5, 5>}

        vector1 = new Vector<int>(4); //vector1 == {<4, 4, 4, 4>}
        vector2 = new Vector<int>(3); //vector2 == {<3, 3, 3, 3>}
        mask = Vector.GreaterThan(vector1, vector2); //mask == {<-1, -1, -1, -1>}
        selected = Vector.ConditionalSelect(mask, vector1, vector2); //selected == {<4, 4, 4, 4>}

        mask = new Vector<int>(123); //mask == {<123, 123, 123, 123>}
        selected = Vector.ConditionalSelect(mask, vector1, vector2); //selected == {<0, 0, 0, 0>}

        mask = new Vector<int>(4);
        selected = Vector.ConditionalSelect(mask, vector1, vector2); //selected == {<7, 7, 7, 7>}
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to use if condition in intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38006616) has some other comments and examples on how to branchlessly handle per-element conditions with SIMD.  Sometimes you can use a simple AND instead of `ConditionalSelect`, if making some elements of the input or output all-zero works.  (zero is the identity value for integer add/sub/xor/or, and for FP add/sub.)  Another example with C++ intrinsics: caseflip ASCII letters only: [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936844)